# Debugging the server project while running out-of-browser?

Tags: silverlight, debugging, out-of-browser

When I start my Silverlight 4 and 5 applications with debugging in VS 2010, I can set breakpoints in both the client project as well as the server project that serves the application.

On running the app out-of-browser (ie configuring the app out-of-browser and setting it as the startup project) however, the debugger will not be attached to the server any longer, although the server project will still be started correctly.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: You can attach to the server project manually, using Debug > Attach To Process, and choosing the `WebDev.WebServer40.EXE` process.  I don't know of a way to do this automatically when debugging an OOB application, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a Launch or Break statement at the location you want to break.

```
// Will launch a debugger once and will break once
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

//Will launch a debugger and break any time the code is hit
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Comment: Accepting this as long as no one answers how to do it automatically in my scenario, as there might well be no better answer. And +1 for .Launch(), didn't know about this either.